# How can I rebase from specific develop branch commit to specific master branch commit

Tags: git, github, rebase, git-rebase

I have the master branch like this:

```
A->B->C->D->E
```

The develop branch like this:

```
A->B->C->D->E->F->G->H->I
                  ^
                  |- This should be used
```

I want to apply `G` on top of `D`. How can I do this?

I tried this:

```
git checkout develop
git rebase 82c7b6a
```

But that is giving me merge conflicts.

My main goal is to keep the master branch and delete the develop branch.

main: `A->B->C->D->G->H->I`

Comment: Well  this graph is means the following for me: branch `develop` was branched off from commit `E` from `master` is this right?

Comment: Yes, but something happened at E that causes issues so I wish to ignore E and F.

Comment: Ok so if you don't mind in history rewriting, which will take place in both cases `git rebase` and `git rebase -i` I prefer to use `git rebase -i` and just kill the commits `E` and `F`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would cherry-pick that one commit.

```
git checkout master
git cherry-pick G
git cherry-pick H  (EDIT 3)
git cherry-pick I  (EDIT 3)
git branch -D develop
```

**EDIT**

I didn't see that you don't want E. Then it would be:

```
git checkout master
git reset --hard HEAD^1
git cherry-pick G
git cherry-pick H  (EDIT 3)
git cherry-pick I  (EDIT 3)
git branch -D develop
```

**EDIT 2**

More failsafe solution would be as pointed out by @ckruczek to use rebase interactive.

```
git checkout master
git reset --hard develop
git rebase -i D
git branch -D develop
```

And remove the lines with the commits you don't want to have.

**EDIT 4**

As it is a history rewrite you might get serious trouble using the upper approaches.

I would recommend a solution like:

`A->B->C->D->E->!E->G->H->I`

To get that do:
    git checkout master
    git revert E
    git cherry-pick G H I
    git branch -D develop

Comment: If I follow EDIT 1, when I cherry-pick G it will grab everything after `G` right? And that `-D` is the SHA of the commit?

Comment: @J_Strauton no, it will only grab the 1 commit. It will also give it a new commit hash

Comment: Then that's a problem. I require everything after that commit as well. I want to end up with `A->B->C->D->G->H->I`

Comment: @J_Strauton use the rebase option then

Comment: I Added commits H and I and @ckruczek you're totally right. I thought that would be clear - but to give a clean solution I added a `git revert` variant which keeps E so that the history isn't rewritten.

Answer (score 0):

If you are the only user try this.

```
1. git checkout develop
2. git rebase --onto master~1 F I  /* move commits G, H and I on master~1 (D) */
3. git checkout I
4. git rebase master
```

finally you can delete the branch develop

```
7. git branch -D develop
```

Comment: Although it should work, cherry-picking commits 1 by 1 is not ideal :P what if there are 100 commits?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to skip `E`-`F` you could do fully explicit rebase:

```
git rebase --onto master G~1 develop
```

you will have to resolve potential conflicts.

When you are done you may move your master and drop develop:

```
git push . develop:master
git checkout master
git branch -d develop
```